# Batch code to display target of a desktop application shortcut

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe, shortcuts

I have been working on expanding a basic batch to pull ip information to include other information relevant to my IT department at work. My department does troubleshooting nationwide for our Cisco equipment on the end user and our servers. So far I have the file pulling up ipconfig details and the mac address with some exclusions. Here is my code so far:

```
@echo off
echo Listed below is your network IP information and physical MAC address.
echo\
echo I am logged as %UserName%.
echo My computer's name is %ComputerName%.
echo My IP settings are
ipconfig | find "." | find /i /v ""
echo\
echo My Mac address is
getmac | find /i /v "disconnected" | find /i /v "not present"
echo\
echo Provide this information to the IT team. 
echo Press the Space bar to close this window.
echo\
pause > nul
```

I've been browsing here and other such sites for relative examples I might be able to modify, but apparently I just stink at non-Cisco stuff. Here is the new code pulled from another article, currently as its own batch:

```
@echo off

Setlocal Enableextensions
Setlocal Enabledelayedexpansion

for /r %%X in (*.URL) do (
  set shortcut="%%X"
  echo SHORTCUT: !shortcut!


     for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('findstr URL !shortcut!') do (
     set URL=%%i
 echo.
 echo URL PATH: !URL!
 )

echo ----------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
)

:end
Pause
```

The output I get from running this is:

```
SHORTCUT: "C:\Users\***\Desktop\Application Catalog, IE only.url"

URL PATH: http://***/cmapplicationcatalog/#/SoftwareLibrary/AppListPageView.xaml
----------------------------------------------------------------

SHORTCUT: "C:\Users\***\Desktop\Test Yahoo.url"

URL PATH: http://www.yahoo.com/
----------------------------------------------------------------

Press any key to continue . . .
```

*** are paths I've truncated.

When I get it working, I will be combining these altogether. What I am trying to get from the 2nd batch is a specific file on every PCs desktop we have called CDK Drive to have its target information pulled. In the target is a complete ip address (http://***.**.**.*/) that I need. The target type of the shortcut is Application, and the type of file itself is Shortut(.lnk). An example of the target is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://***.**.209.42/bin/start/wsStart.application
```

I'm trying to give as much specific information as possible so that I can get the most accurate assistance with this.

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:
So, I've made a little headway using Powershell and having that be ran by my batch. This is my Powershell code so far, and it 'almost' works as intended.

```
function Get-StartMenuShortcuts
{
$Shortcuts = Get-ChildItem -Recurse "$Env:C:\Users\alexandm\Desktop\Batching" -Include *.lnk
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell

foreach ($Shortcut in $Shortcuts)
{
$Properties = @{
ShortcutName = $Shortcut.Name
Target = $Shell.CreateShortcut($Shortcut).targetpath
}

New-Object PSObject -Property $Properties
}

[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Shell) | Out-Null
}

$Output = Get-StartMenuShortcuts
$Output
```

When ran from my batch, I get output that shows me the basic target path, which happens to be to iexplore.exe, but it doesnt give me the whole target path including the ip address we add. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the code you already have?

Comment: Unlike `.url` or `.website` links,  `.lnk` shorcuts are not plain text  files. You need to treat them e.g. using a [`COM` object](http://stackoverflow.com/a/534409/3439404)

Comment: All of the code I have is already included above. As for the "COM object", how would I put that to use here for the specific file and target path I need from it? Frankly, I just can't build code like this from scratch, and am very new as to even modifying it.

Comment: @JosefZ I added some PowerShell code to the end that almost works as intended, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your powershell code could be as follows:

```
$shell = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell
Get-ChildItem -Recurse "$env:UserProfile\Desktop\*.lnk","$env:PUBLIC\Desktop\*.lnk" | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $shortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut($_.FullName)
        $Args = $shortcut.Arguments
        if ( $Args -match [system.Uri]::SchemeDelimiter) {
            "shortcut: $($_.Name)"
            "exe path: $($shortcut.TargetPath)"
            "link URL: $($Args)"
            "---"
        }
    }
```

Omitted all that *function* and *PSObject* stuff (supposing it's a one-shot script which would merely *display* a result).

- `[system.Uri]::SchemeDelimiter` [Uri field, see `.NET` URI Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri_fields(v=vs.110).aspx) is used to simply check whether `$shortcut.Arguments` could be `URI` (specifies the characters that separate the communication protocol scheme from the address portion of the `URI`); as currently written, the script does not care about protocol and its validity.

**Updated**.  Now are processed all `.lnk` files folder from *current user*'s desktop **and** from *public* desktop **recursively**.

Comment: I'll have to test this later and see how it works for me. Yes, this is a one-shot command just to get a result. In this end, when running the batch, I'll get ipconfig info, mac address, and this pwrshell providing the target data from that shortcut ALL of our users have.

Comment: I tried running that as is, and I get no output. Do I need to modify any to reference the shortcut named "CDK Drive"? Tried tinkering and only managed errors. 
Tried running on its own and from the batch for a readout. Blank. 
Also, do I need to add anything equivalent to the 'pause' command to get powershell to stay open to view its results?

Comment: `pause` is valid Powershell command. Check if your `.lnk` is rather in _public_ desktop, try `Get-ChildItem "$env:PUBLIC\Desktop\*.lnk"`.

Comment: @MichaelAlexander Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Ok, awesome! Thank you. I now get the full target path of that link. Next part I was trying to do, if possible, was either filter or extract just the "http;//123.45.67.89" ip address. Is that something that can be done? I'm trying to have it be as user friendly and simple as possible so they don't have to hunt out the ip address from the full link. Some people I work with wont know what an ip address is lol.

Comment: `$Args -match 'http' + [system.Uri]::SchemeDelimiter + '123\.45\.67\.89'` Note that full stops are escaped. `$Args -match 'http://123\.45\.67\.89'` is possible as well (but you have a semicolon instead of colon there).

Comment: So I guess in this specific case it looks like I could extract a given IP address if i knew what it would be. This is an instance where I need the IP because it can change depending on what server they're using. Not a huge deal, and I'll tinker with it. This is more aesthetics at this point to clean up the data output. Thank you so much for your help sir.